# Selenium Get Value Job Id Glassdoor

Tags: python, selenium, scrape

I try scrape Glassdoor using Selenium, part of scrape data is Job ID

[Source Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGwFm.png)

And this is my code

```
                try:
                        
                job_id = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//ul[contains(@class, "job-search-key")]/li').get_attribute('data-id')
            except NoSuchElementException:
                job_id = -1
```

code successfully retrieved the value on `data-id` but unfortunately the data-id value taken is the same, your help will be very much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: can you share ALL your code or at least more code?

Comment: Update the question with the text based HTML of the desired element.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear enough.
I guess you have to change from `find_element_by_xpath` to `find_elements_by_xpath` to get a list of web element**s** and then to iterate over that list to extract `data-id` attribute from each element.
Something like this:

```py
jobs = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//ul[contains(@class, "job-search-key")]/li')
for job in jobs:
    job_id = job.get_attribute('data-id')
```